# getting error while implement connection pooling through jdbc using oracle databse

Tags: java, database

While working on some code I got followinh error,The code and the error is as given below,Tell me if further explanations required.. ............

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.*;
import javax.naming.directory.*;



public class OracleDataSourceRegisterJNDI {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // Set up data source reference data for naming context:
        // ----------------------------------------------------
        // Create a class instance that implements the interface
        // ConnectionPoolDataSource
        OracleDataSource ds = new OracleDataSource();
        ds.setDescription(
        "Oracle on Sparky - Oracle Data Source");
        ds.setServerName("sparky");
        ds.setPortNumber(1521);
        ds.setUser("scott");
        ds.setPassword("test");
        // Set up environment for creating initial context
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
        "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "file:c:\\JDBCDataSource");
        Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);
        // Register the data source to JNDI naming service
        ctx.bind("jdbc/ConnectSparkyOracle", ds);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return;
        }
        }
}
```

i want to use connection pooling using oracle database i am getting following error please help me out.

>

ERROR:;

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory]
```

Comment: and what version of jdk you are using

Comment: i am using jdk 1.6 @Satya

Comment: May be this will help you. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21408217

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the code. But this is a classpath issue, you are missing the required jar from classpath. Refer: http://www.findjar.com/class/com/sun/jndi/fscontext/RefFSContextFactory.html

Comment: Thanks for the response,but i am getting a new error now,javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'c:\JDBCDataSource'

Comment: Now I guess this is your code. Env setup wise things look ok. As I mentioned I am not sure about the code, you might have study a bit before implementing